# Como fazer autenticação em aplicação MVC com linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Tenho um projeto em ASP.Net MVC e estou colocando a autentificação manualmente. Tudo está indo bem, mas usei como referencia um projeto já pronto que usa o EntityFramework, mas quero usar o linq para minhas operações.
O problema está ocorrendo no código abaixo:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

O erro gerado é:

> Error 2   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Bem, como eu poderia resolver esse problema sem usar o EntityFramework? Existe alguma forma de usar apenas o linq para autenticação segura?
Pesquisei bastante, mas não encontrei nada do tipo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque você adicionou o Entity Framework no seu projeto de maneira irregular. O correto é adicionar por pacote. Abra o Package Manager Console (<kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>) e digite:

> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.2

Procure não instalar versões beta. Na data desta resposta, há duas versões beta em desenvolvimento.

O comando não apenas instala o pacote pra você corretamente como também configura alguns arquivos com entradas que são necessárias pro Entity Framework ser reconhecido, como o `Web.config` do diretório raiz.

Isto resolve o problema que gera o erro, mas não exclui o uso do Entity Framework, que acredito ser o objetivo da pergunta.

Neste caso, é errado você usar uma classe derivada de `IdentityDbContext` [porque `IdentityDbContext` faz parte do Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

O correto é você derivar uma outra classe chamada [`SignInManager`](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/2.2.0-alpha1-140723/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SignInManager.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin), que faz parte do [OWIN](http://owin.org/), padrão Web definido pela Microsoft:

```
public class MinhaImplementacaoDeSignInManager : SignInManager<MinhaClasseDeUsuario, string>
{
    // Implemente os métodos aqui
}
```

`MinhaClasseDeUsuario` precisa implementar a interface [`Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<TKey>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613291%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Se precisar de mais ajuda nos métodos, posso esmiuçar ainda mais a pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta meu amigo, mas o objetivo é colocar autenticação sem o EntityFramework...

Comment: Sim, já estou editando a resposta. Um momento só.